# jquery function executing twice even after clearing the DOM using empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Jquery function is executing twice(or the times if i go forward and then back). onLoad of LoginMenu.jsp ,WorkOrder.jsp is loaded in **whatever** id.

When WorkOrder.jsp loads it then loads the schedule.jsp in schedule tab defined in WorkOrders.jsp

When Schedule.jsp loads it fetches the records and prints in schedule page which consist of two bootstrap dropdown buttons and a link upon which it will take you to another page. onclick of a link present in schedule.jsp it empties the **whatever** div and load the SubcaseMain.jsp.

Subcasemain.jsp contains the back button upon clicked it empties the whatever div and loads the WorkOrder.jsp.so when i click on link present in schedule.jsp it goes to click(.delete) function present in WorkOrder.jsp twice and load the modal X number of times the function is present.I have checked the div it is emptied.So why the function is executing many times ?

tag is clear after calling empty method ,but its still in memory ,i have checked the firebug script tab in which it is making multiple sources of javascript.Why js is not cleared even after calling the empty method ??

> LoginMenu.jsp

```
        <link href="css_harish/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css_harish/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css_harish/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css_harish/bootstrap-paper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js_harish/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js_harish/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js_harish/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js_harish/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="js_harish/bootbox.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js_harish/validator.js"></script>
        <script src="js_harish/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js_harish/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css_harish/Loader.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="content" id="whatever"></div>  

    $(document).ready(function () {
           $(function () {
               $("#whatever").empty();
               $("#whatever").load("WorkOrders.jsp");
           });
       });
```

> WorkOrders.jsp

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#schedule .showbox").show();
    $("#schedule").load("Schedule.jsp");
});
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        //delete the appointment
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("delete");
        $("#edit_objid").val($(this).data('id'));
        var objid = $("#edit_objid").val();
        bootbox.confirm({
            title: 'Delete Appointment',
            message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this Appointment. ?',
            buttons: {
                'cancel': {
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    className: 'btn-default pull-left'
                },
                'confirm': {
                    label: 'Delete',
                    className: 'btn-danger pull-right'
                }
            },
            callback: function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    url="deleteAppointment.action?objid="+objid;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache: false,
                        async: true,
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(typeof data['EXCEPTION']!="undefined"){
                                bootbox.alert("Exception Occurs while deleting the appointment :"+data.EXCEPTION);
                            }else{
                                bootbox.alert("Deleted Successfully."); 
                                $("#containerid").html('');
                                $("#containerid").html($(".showbox").html());
                                getSchedule();
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

> Schedule.jsp

```
$(document).on("click", ".opensubcase", function() {
    var id_number=$(this).text();
    $("#whatever").empty();
    $("#whatever").load("SubCaseMain.jsp?id_number="+id_number);
});
```

> SubcaseMain.jsp

```
    <span style="float:left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Go Back"><img
        style="float: left" class="back" src="back.png" width="35px"
        height="35px" /></span> 

$(document).on("click", ".back", function() {
    $("#whatever").empty();
    $("#whatever").load("WorkOrders.jsp");
});
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox i have made the changes ,please check now

Comment: You're using delegated binding on a class... so if the element with a `back` class is nested inside an element with a `delete` class, you'll see things happen twice. Maybe you could try adding a stop immediate propagation?

Comment: and don't use `alert`, use `console.log` and check the browser console (press `F12`).

Comment: @Mottie How come ? <script> tag is inside the whatever div ,so once emptied it should be clear . when i am going back again whatever div is emptied and loads the fresh page.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
           $(function () {` wraps a document ready in a document ready which makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are binding multiple click events for the back button, try using 
`$(document).one("click", ".back", function() {});`

instead

`$(document).on("click", ".back", function() {});`

example:

```js
$(document).one('click', '#clickOnce', function(){
  alert('clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='clickOnce'>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how the script is parsed and put in the page DOM.  Removing the script tag once  it has parsed and executed does not remove it.

See this markup and code for example:

Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">wrap it up
  <button id="howdy">
    howdy
  </button>
  <div id="whatever">
    <div class='inside'>insidetop</div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#howdy').on('click', function() {
          console.log('howdyclick from org');
        })
      });

    </script>
    <div class='inside'>inside</div>
  </div>
  <button id="test">
    test
  </button>
</div>
```

Code:(not in the  markup)

```
console.clear();
var testthing = "<scr"+"ipt>$(document).ready(function(){$('#howdy').on('click', function(){console.log('howdyclick from test');});});</scr"+"ipt> <div class='inside'>inside</div>";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#howdy').on('click', function() {
    console.log('howdyclick from outside');
  })
});
$('#test').on('click', function() {
  $('#whatever').empty();
  $('#whatever').html(testthing);
});
```

Now when you  execute this, you can click the "howdy" button. you  get the first line of this in console, note that the second line is from the outside handler.

```
howdyclick from org
howdyclick from outside
```

Now click the "test" button which puts NEW script and markup as you have done.
Now click the "howdy" button again - see you STILL get the response from the original code inside the "whatever" which now has new markup and script - which then adds the THIRD line.  So you see the original still exists and executes.

```
howdyclick from org
howdyclick from outside
howdyclick from test
```

I put a fiddle together so you could see for for yourself here https://jsfiddle.net/8fwfoc5b/